# Python Condition If Text Present In Webpage Using Selenium

Tags: python

I m trying to make condition if text is present on webpage then go to my desired urls.I tried to make my code for that but unfortunately my code is not working properly and giving the invalid syntax error when i m running the code.Here is the code that i m using below.What is the problem in my code?

```
import re
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
import random
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/liyanakasini')
    if(browser.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/div/h2")).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("This Account is Private")):
    {
        browser.get('http://google.com')
    }

    else
    {
        browser.get('http://yahoo.com')
    }
```

Comment: There are no curly braces (`{` and `}`) in Python `if/else` blocks.

Comment: Flow control statements end with `:` in Python.

Comment: I m getting error expected an indent block error now

Comment: You should read more about Python fundamentals. See @emeraldemon's answer.

Comment: i tried code using it but not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is indented when it shouldn't be.  And python doesn't use `{}` like other languages.  I'd recommend a python tutorial before you worry about selenium.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html